# Why do I need to call StateHasChanged() when I make a child component visible?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor (InteractiveServer) page which has an AzureMapsControl (Blazor component wrapping Azure Maps). It also has a DxPopup component on the page.

```
<div class="search-results--map">
    <AzureMap Id="map"
              @ref="MyMap"
              CameraOptions="new CameraOptions { Zoom = 12 }"
              Controls="new Control[]
                  {
                      new ZoomControl(new ZoomControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.TopLeft),
                      new CompassControl(new CompassControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.BottomLeft),
                      new StyleControl(new StyleControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto, MapStyles = MapStyle.All() }, ControlPosition.BottomRight)
                  }"
              StyleOptions='new StyleOptions { ShowLogo = false, Language = "en-US" }'
              EventActivationFlags="MapEventActivationFlags
                  .None()
                  .Enable(MapEventType.Ready, MapEventType.SourceAdded, MapEventType.Click, MapEventType.DragEnd)"
              OnReady="OnMapReadyAsync"
              OnSourceAdded="OnDatasourceAdded"
              OnDragEnd="OnMapDragEnd" />
</div>

<DxPopup AllowDrag="true"
         @bind-Visible="@EventPopupVisible"
         CloseOnEscape="true"
         CloseOnOutsideClick="true"
         HeaderText="@EventPopupHeader"
         ZIndex="10000">
    <BodyContentTemplate>
        <EventCard Value="@EventCardData" 
                   ReturnUrl="@ReturnUrl"/>
    </BodyContentTemplate>
</DxPopup>
```

The popup is initially hidden. When I do set it to show, I do the following:

```
EventCardData = Data!.EventData.First(e => e.UnderlyingEvent!.Id == eventId);
EventPopupVisible = true;

Task.Run(async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
```

If I don't call StateHasChanged() then the popup is not visible until I drag the map or otherwise cause rendering. Why? Isn't changing the EventPopup.Visible sufficient to cause the popup to render? As it's set to `@bind-Visible`, that means an event on DxPopup is firing.

Comment: Not enough info. How is the `EventPopupVisible = true;` code called? we een the full path.

Comment: `Task.Run(async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));` is absolutely horrible.

Comment: Can you show the full code? StateHasChanged is automatically called only in response to a UI event in the component. If visibility is changing from the code, it won't trigger a StateHasChnaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Educated guesswork, but you probably have something like this:

```cs
private void SomeEventHandler(SomeEventArgs e)
{
EventCardData = Data!.EventData.First(e => e.UnderlyingEvent!.Id == eventId);
EventPopupVisible = true;

Task.Run(async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
}
```

So, if you have to call `StateHasChanged` to update the UI then `SomeEventHandler` is being called by a standard event, not a UI event.  Probably an `Action` or `Func` defined as a parameter in `AzureMap` rather than an `EventCallback` that would trigger a render in the parent.  Maybe even an `event` wired up thro `MyMap`.

This line is a little crazy.  You spin up a threadpool thread to call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` which immediately switches execution back to the *Synchronisation Context* thread in order to run `StateHasChanged`.

```cs
Task.Run(async () => await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
```

This should work:

```cs
private void SomeEventHandler(object? sender, SomeEventArgs e)
//or
private void SomeEventHandler(SomeEventArgs e)
{
EventCardData = Data!.EventData.First(e => e.UnderlyingEvent!.Id == eventId);
EventPopupVisible = true;

StateHasChanged();
// or 
// depending on whether this is being invoked on a threadpool thread or the synchronisation context
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> As it's set to @bind-Visible, that means an event on DxPopup is firing.

This seems to be the main point of confusion.

The code `@bind-Visible="@EventPopupVisible"` will not receive or cause any event when `EventPopupVisible` changes. Initiative flows the other way: it may cause an event to update `EventPopupVisible` in the owning component (value comes *from* the popup), for example when the Popup closes.

Changing `EventPopupVisible` will only take effect (value goes *into* the popup) when the owner is re-rendering (and EventPopupVisible has changed). Hence the need for StateHasChanged().